# Type Load Exception in EF Core Project

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API application using EF Core. This is the my configuration in the `ConfigureServices` method of the `Startup` class:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(options =>
options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("AppConn")));
```

The above configuration tested and works for a SQL Server database.

Then I switched to using Sqlite after installing its package successfully.

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(options =>
     options.UseSqlite("Data Source=sqlitedemo.db"));
```

But when I try to add the EF migration

```
add-migration initial -context ApplicationContext
```

I get this error:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>
> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.SemanticVersionComparer' from assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
>
> { Stack trace }
>
> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Comment: You seem to have EF Core related package versions mismatch. Please include the EF Core related project package references (all entries from .csproj staring with `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.`)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Please update to your entity framework core  nuget package  to 3.1.10(or latest 5.0.0). It will solve your problem.

Comment: I was helped by this answer, but have an experience to share, the version of Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools suddenly jumped back from 5x to 3x after having deleted all migrations and trying adding "first" migration. Also, check the .csproj file.

Answer (score 31):

I had EF Core 5 package installed, but not `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design` and one package were implicitly referencing older version (`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design 3.0.0`).

Installing explicit dependency on `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design 5.x.x` resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 11):

I had this issue in a .NET Core 3.1 project. I fixed it by installing the package     **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design** in the startup project

Comment: The issue is which Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design  did you install?

Comment: I have netcoreapp3.1 application with EF5
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.5" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="5.0.5" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="5.0.5" />

Answer (score 7):

Do not forget that for migrations, you must have the packages installed both in the main EntityFramework project and in the startup project.

```
Microsoft.EntityFramework.Core
Microsoft.EntityFramework.Core.Design
```

Comment: `error: There are no versions available for the package 'Microsoft.EntityFramework.Core`

Comment: `error: There are no versions available for the package 'Microsoft.EntityFramework.Core.Design`

Answer (score 7):

Make sure that **each project** referenced pulls in the **same** major/minor version of the Entity Framework nuget package.

---

I upgraded a project from V3 to V6 and didn't upgrade the EF Core nuget packages to 6. One project had 6 while the other had 3 and was receiving this error when I did an `update-database`.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue when all the dependencies seemed correct in my project. But the issue was that the context was in one project in the solution and a different project in the solution was the *start-up project.* And that project happened to include a different version of EFCore.

Using the context's project as the start-up project in the Package Manager Console resolved the issue for me.

`add-migration -startupproject myProjectWithTheMigration`

Answer (score 4):

I was getting this error using the latest `V7` of EF Core that was released recently. Downgrading to `V6` fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to do migration, make sure install *Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools*

Answer (score 1):

This one nailed me too with EF 7. If you're utilizing lazy loading, make sure to have the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies` packaged referenced as well.

Comment: Aha! This was indeed my problem with type loading. Did not help that the error emits an `assembly Version=6.0.0.0`!